# Test if column name contains string in R

Tags: r

I'm attempting to test if each of the column names in my dataframe contain a particular string (in this case "Fld". My attempt below is not compiling and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
varnames <-colnames(data)
for (i in 1:len(varnames)){
  if grepl("Fld",varnames[i])==TRUE {
    print varnames[i]
  }
}
```

Comment: try `indx <- grepl('Fld', colnames(data))` would be enough to test.  If you want to extract the columns, `data[indx]` or the column names `colnames(data)[indx]`

Comment: Why are you indexing by `[0]`? That returns an empty vector every time. I think you want `varnames[i]`. Also, its `print(varnames[i])` with the parens. However, akrun's solution is superior to the loop.

Comment: thanks for the catch. using the zero index was a typo! and agreed - akun's solution is nice!

Comment: I posted the comment as a solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We can use `grep` to get the index of column names that have 'Fld'

```
indx <- grepl('Fld', colnames(data))
```

and use that to subset the 'data'

```
 data[indx]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are just wanting to 'test if [a] column name contains a string' in R, I would use the `any()` function around @akrun's nice answer:

```
if(any(grepl("Fld", colnames(data)))){
   print("True")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Making more simple !

```
data[grepl('Fld', colnames(data))]
```